# In aframe, how do you make the property visible="false" ignore the raycaster?

Tags: aframe

I have some objects in aframe with visible="false" meaning they aren't visible but they are still interactable even though you can't see them. Is there a solution to this?

Found a few similar cases online but no clear solution.

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3551
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/979

```
<!-- CURSOR ENTITY -->
        <a-entity rotation="0 0 0" position="0 0 2">
            <a-entity id="camera" far: 20; camera look-controls rotation="0 0 0" wasd-controls>
                <!-- MAIN CURSOR -->
                <a-entity raycaster="interval: 200; objects: .clickable" cursor="fuse: true; maxDistance: 500; timeout: 1500;" id="cursor-main" position="0 0 -1.5" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusOuter: 0.04; radiusInner: 0.03; thetaLength: 360; thetaStart: 90;" material="color: #439DC2;">
                    <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" attribute="geometry.thetaLength" fill="forwards" from="360" to="0" easing="ease-in"></a-animation>
                    <a-animation begin="mouseleave" attribute="geometry.thetaLength" fill="backwards" from="0" to="360" dur="0"></a-animation>
                </a-entity>
                <a-entity id="cursor-loader" position="0 0 -1.51" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusOuter: 0.04; radiusInner: 0.03;" material="color: #2ADD2A;">
                </a-entity>
            </a-entity>
        </a-entity>
```

```
        <a-entity ui-modal="triggerElement:#selection;" visible="false">

            <a-image position="-0.7 -1 1" class="clickable" src="#one" scale="0.7 0.7 0" link="href:location1.html; on: click; visualAspectEnabled: false" src-fit></a-image>

        <a-image position="0 -1 1" class="clickable" src="#two" scale="0.7 0.64 0" link="href:location2.html; on: click; visualAspectEnabled: false" src-fit></a-image>

             <a-image position="0.7 -1 1" class="clickable" src="#three" scale="0.7 0.7 0" link="href:location3.html; on: click; visualAspectEnabled: false" src-fit></a-image>

            <a-image class="clickable" src="#close" id="closing" scale="0.3 0.3 0" position="-0.5 -0.35 1.1"></a-image>

        </a-entity>
```

Ideally if an object is set to visible="false" the user shouldn't be able to interact with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the [discussion](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3551#issuecomment-395292431), if you want to ignore certain objects, you should not rely on visibility. The proper way would be using the `objects` whitelist:

```
<a-scene cursor raycaster='objects: .clickable>
```

The whitelist uses typical CSS selectors, so in the above example the raycaster would only interact with elements which have a `clickable` class.

You can add / remove it with the visibility:

```
if (condition) {
  el.setAttribute('visible', 'false')
  el.classList.remove('clickable')
} else {
  el.setAttribute('visible', 'true')
  el.classList.add('clickable')
}
```

You can check it out in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/yxfdcL70/) fiddle. Click the sphere to make the box clickable / not clickable.

---

A hacky workaround could be also setting the `scale` to `0 0 0`. The element won't be visible, and won't be clickable.